# C++ errors when concatenating metadata in LLVM API

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm writing an LLVM frontend and want to set alias.scope and noalias metadata to my memory operations. I've found some code in an pass (LoopVersioningLICM) to find an example of how this is done with the API:

```cpp
void LoopVersioningLICM::setNoAliasToLoop(Loop *VerLoop) {
  // Get latch terminator instruction.
  Instruction *I = VerLoop->getLoopLatch()->getTerminator();
  // Create alias scope domain.
  MDBuilder MDB(I->getContext());
  MDNode *NewDomain = MDB.createAnonymousAliasScopeDomain("LVDomain");
  StringRef Name = "LVAliasScope";
  MDNode *NewScope = MDB.createAnonymousAliasScope(NewDomain, Name);
  SmallVector<Metadata *, 4> Scopes{NewScope}, NoAliases{NewScope};
  // Iterate over each instruction of loop.
  // set no-alias for all load & store instructions.
  for (auto *Block : CurLoop->getBlocks()) {
    for (auto &Inst : *Block) {
      // Only interested in instruction that may modify or read memory.
      if (!Inst.mayReadFromMemory() && !Inst.mayWriteToMemory())
        continue;
      // Set no-alias for current instruction.
      Inst.setMetadata(
          LLVMContext::MD_noalias,
          MDNode::concatenate(Inst.getMetadata(LLVMContext::MD_noalias),
                              MDNode::get(Inst.getContext(), NoAliases)));
      // set alias-scope for current instruction.
      Inst.setMetadata(
          LLVMContext::MD_alias_scope,
          MDNode::concatenate(Inst.getMetadata(LLVMContext::MD_alias_scope),
                              MDNode::get(Inst.getContext(), Scopes)));
    }
  }
}
```

So I've copied the line to set metadata in my own function (called with my own C wrapper):

```cpp
void set_noalias(LLVMValueRef instruction, SmallVector<Metadata *, 4> Scope){
    Instruction *I = reinterpret_cast<Instruction *>(instruction);

    I->setMetadata(
        LLVMContext::MD_noalias,
        MDNode::concatenate(I->getMetadata(LLVMContext::MD_noalias),
                            MDNode::get(I->getContext(), Scope))
    );
}
```

But this causes errors for me. Firstly, on `I->getcontext()`:

`Cannot initialize object parameter of type 'const llvm::Value' with an expression of type 'Instruction'`

And then if I hack this away by passing the required `LLVMContext` value directly as an argument, I then get on the `MDNode::get()` call:

`Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'MDNode *' with an rvalue of type 'MDTuple *'`

This is because `MDNode::get()` returns an `MDTuple *` but `MDNode::concatenate()` expects two `MDNode *` values. But the LLVM code passes an `MDTuple *` instead without any errors.

I'm unsure what the differences could be between my code and the LLVM code I'm looking at, is anyone able to explain what's going on and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please unpack the different expressions into separate lines (the I->getMetadata, the MDNode::get, then MDNode::concatenate, then I->setMetadata) and look report back with what and where the compiler error is? Please use the I->getContext() form not the other "pass in LLVMContext&" form you mentioned in your post.

Comment: MDTuple derives from MDNode so any code that takes an MDNode* may receive an MDTuple*.

Comment: I'm using an LSP that highlights the specific characters. The first error occurs at `I->getContext()` (and no further errors when using this), and the second error when passing the context object directly occurs at `MDNode::get(`.